# How to make a reverse way in ZenCoding

Tags: emmet

Is possible in Zencoding in the opposite way?

For example, i have the HTML code

```
<div id="test"><span></span></div>
```

=> i mark this block of code , push some shortcut and result is `div#test>span`

Need opposite way in ZenCoding (for some testing and any adjustments to the existing code generated)

Thanks

(Im using Sublime Text with ZenCoding (new with newest Emmet)

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in current version.

There is a thread about this feature request: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/93

Feel free to join and discuss.